# Como pegar valores com espaço no JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Olá.
Estou com um problema ao popular um select com JSON.
Quando o valor tem 2 ou mais palavras o 'value' do meu option não é preenchido corretamente.
Exemplo:

```
{
"Marcas": {
    "Acura": {
        "Modelos": ["Integra", "Legend", "NSX"]
    },

    "Alfa Romeo": {
        "Modelos": ["145", "147", "155"]
    }
}


$.getJSON('models.json', function(data) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        $.each(val, function(make, value){
            console.log(make, value)
            var option = '<option value='+make+'>'+make+'</option>';
            $(option).appendTo("#marcas_list");
        });
    });
});
```

Results:

[image: Select]

[image: Console]

Note que o `<option value="Alfa" romeo></option>` está sendo preenchido de forma incorreta.

Alguma coisa errada com o código ?
Alguma sugestão ?

Abraços!

Comment: Como queres que apareça? Testa por exemplo: `var option = '<option value="'+make.join(' ')+'">'+make.join(' ')+'</option>';` é parecido com o que procuras?

Comment: boa prática é quando a chave ( pode ser variável ) tiver mais de uma palavra usar minúsculo e juntas por um hífen, assim impede esses problemas , se você puder mudar essa parte evitaria esses problemas.

Comment: @Sergio quando tento usar o .join():
Uncaught TypeError: make.join is not a function

Comment: Solução: `var $option = $('<option />')
      .prop('value', make)
      .prop('text', make);
      $("#marcas_list").append($option);`

Answer (score 1):

A separação não tem problema em carregar olha o exemplo!

```js
var items = {
"Marcas": {
    "Acura": {
        "Modelos": ["Integra", "Legend", "NSX"]
    },
    "Alfa Romeo": {
        "Modelos": ["145", "147", "155"]
    }
}};

var opt = "";
$.each(items.Marcas, function( key, val ) 
{
 opt = opt + '<option value="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>';
});
$("#marcas_list").html(opt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="marcas_list">
</select>
```

**No seu código:**

```
$.getJSON('models.json', function(data) {
    var opt = "";
    $.each( data.Marcas, function( key, val ) {
        opt = opt + '<option value="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>';
    });
    $("#marcas_list").html(opt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso sem problema através de objeto, usando `document.createElement`.

```js
var marcas = {
"Marcas" : {
    "Acura": {
        "Modelos": ["Integra", "Legend", "NSX"]
    },
    "Alfa Romeo" : {
        "Modelos": ["145", "147", "155"]
    }
}}
  
$.each(marcas['Marcas'], function(key, value){
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent = key;
  option.value = key;
  $('#options').append(option);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="options"></select>
```

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou também!
A solução que utilizei foi essa:

https://jsfiddle.net/xqgaevzo/